# Azure function - CosmosDB with Mongoose disconnect database

Tags: mongoose, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

i seek your guidance on developing application on Azure Function. i am using CosmosDB with /enableMongoDBENdpoint.  I would like to know for each of my azure functions, do i need to disconnect the DB?
Here is example of one of my code using Node.JS in azure function:

```
const { connectDB, disconnectDB } = require('../config/db');



module.exports = async function (context, req) {
     
    try {


        const {
          testData
        } = req.body;


        const addTestData = {
           testData
        };
        

          //
         //open MongoDB Connection, each azure function will call this function
        //

        connectDB();
        /********************/
        /*
         ## connectDB code commented for clarity ##
       
           const connectDB = async () => {
             try {
               await mongoose.connect(db, {
               useNewUrlParser: true,
               useCreateIndex: true,
               useFindAndModify: false
              });
           } catch (err) {
              console.error(err.message);
              //Exit process with failure
              process.exit(1);
          }
       };
     
   */
     /*********************/
       
        //
       // Remove code that do the usual DB add
      //   

       //
      // send success to clien
     //
      context.json.send({msg: 'Success'});
    }
    catch (err) {

        context.res.status(500).send('Server Error' + err.message);
    }
    finally {
 
        //do i need to disconnect the DB? 
         disconnectDB();

        /**************************/
        # Code for disconnectDB()         
        const disconnectDB = async () => {
              try {
                   mongoose.connection.close();
                   console.log('Disconnect from DB');
              } 
              catch (err) {
                 console.log(err);
              }
           };
         */
       /***********************/
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you developing your solution in the Azure Portal or are you using Visual Studio? Visual Studio is preferred but I will provide you an example of each:

- Create a function triggered by Azure Cosmos DB ([link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-cosmos-db-triggered-function))

> Learn how to create a function triggered when data is added to or changed in Azure Cosmos DB. To learn more about Azure Cosmos DB, see [Azure Cosmos DB: Serverless database computing using Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/serverless-computing-database).

Note: The `Serverless database computing using Azure Functions` doc is very useful here as is the Azure Functions version 2.x document below ([Functions 2.x and higher](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-cosmosdb-v2#functions-2x-and-higher)).

- Azure Cosmos DB bindings for Azure Functions [ver. 1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-cosmosdb?tabs=csharp) and [ver. 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-cosmosdb-v2).

> This reference is for Azure Functions version 2.x and higher. For information about how to use these bindings in Functions 1.x, see Azure Cosmos DB bindings for Azure Functions 1.x.

> This binding was originally named DocumentDB. In Functions version 2.x and higher, the trigger, bindings, and package are all named Cosmos DB.

And in a version 2.x Azure Function, you do not need to explicitly close the connection. You simply call the result. Please see: [Azure Cosmos DB input binding for Azure Functions 2.x and higher](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-cosmosdb-v2-input?tabs=csharp)

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace CosmosDBSamplesV2
 {
      public static class DocByIdFromQueryString
      {
    [FunctionName("DocByIdFromQueryString")]
    public static IActionResult Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)]
            HttpRequest req,
        [CosmosDB(
            databaseName: "ToDoItems",
            collectionName: "Items",
            ConnectionStringSetting = "CosmosDBConnection",
            Id = "{Query.id}",
            PartitionKey = "{Query.partitionKey}")] ToDoItem toDoItem,
        ILogger log)
    {
        log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

        if (toDoItem == null)
        {
            log.LogInformation($"ToDo item not found");
        }
        else
        {
            log.LogInformation($"Found ToDo item, Description={toDoItem.Description}");
        }
        return new OkResult();
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. basically i notice that i should not close the connection.